# Are users emailed when their question gets answered?

Tags: support, asking-questions

When a user on Ask Patents posts a question and another responds, is the user who posted the question notified via email that an answer was posted?

Answer (score 1):

They can be, but only if the user selects the check box mentioned while asking the question.

[image]

However this option is not available for first time askers posting as guest (i.e. new user not logged in). Ideally it should be checked by default but currently under user discretion.